# Prevent user to edit other user's profile

Tags: python, flask

I created a function that allows users to edit his profile as follows :

```
@count.route('/employees/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_employee(id):
    """
    Edit a employee
    """

    add_employee = False

    employee = Employee.query.get_or_404(id)
    form = EmployeeForm(obj=employee)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        employee.name = form.name.data
        employee.description = form.description.data
    return render_template('admin/employees/employee.html', 
    add_employee=add_employee, form=form, title="Edit Employee")
```

But the problem is that when the user changes the id in the url bare random it has the possibility of changing the profile of another user.
I'm looking for a solution to use the token but I have not succeeded to do it.

Comment: Create another route wirthout`<int:id>`, obtain `id` from session or encrypted cookie, depending on where you are storing currently logged user data. And limit your current route to administrators only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask-Login supply a proxy called `current_user`, it represents the currently logged user. You can use it to make sure user can only edit himself's profile. You can redirect the user to index page if he wants to edit other user's profile.

```
from flask_login import current_user
# ...
def edit()
    # ...
    employee = Employee.query.get_or_404(id)
    if employee != current_user:
        flash('You can't edit other user's profile.')
        return redirect(url_for('.index'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use Sessions so you know who the current logged in user is. Then compare and see if the current logged in user is trying to edit their own profile, if not redirect them or show them an error message